# Select on many to many relation

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-relationship

I have a two entities `Product(int id ID)` and `Attribute(int id ID)`. Each Product can have multiple Attributes with custom value, so I have a `ProductAttribute(int product_id, int attribute_id, int value)`.

I want to search for products that have attribute 1 with value x and attribute 2 with value y and ... .

Is that possible? And how? Or should I change the relation map?

I'm using MySQL 5.7 if it matters.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use aggregation and `having`:

```
select product_id
from ProductAttribute
where (attribute_id, value) in ( (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4))
group by product_id
having count(*) = 3;
```

The "3" is the number of attributes in the list being compared.

Comment: Tnx. It sounds great, but my real problem is to check `value` between a span. In this case what is the proper query?

Comment: @vakarami . . . You changed the question after I answered it.  That is rude.  It invalidates the answer, which can draw downvotes.